Eclipse MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error In Installed tab when build up to version 4.32.0
An anyone help me with this error when I update to Eclipse version 4.32.0. Thank you
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unexpected response for
 '2306961,1103239,3581018,1617241,4716941,5012014,
4528322,1166,4290168,5026683,5321178,2177882,2433251,264,3184658'

Error log details
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ok4B2F18.png
